# Time Series manipulation

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, time-series

So I have a **dataframe** that I dump a time series into. **The index is the date**. I need to do calculations based on date.

For eg. I have {

```
     XRT_Close
Date                 
2010-01-04      35.94
2010-01-05      36.17
2010-01-06      36.50
...
2015-02-07      36.60
2015-02-08      36.52 }
```

How would I go about doing say... Percentage change of beginning to end of the month? How would I construct a loop to cycle through the months?

Any help will be met with huge appreciation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First create year and month columns:

```
df['year'] = [x.year for x in df.index]
df['month'] = [x.month for x in df.index]
```

Group by them:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['year','month'])
```

Define the function you want to run on the groups:

```
def PChange(df):
    begin = df['column_name'].iloc[0]
    end = df['column_name'].iloc[-1]
    return (end-begin)/(end+begin)*100
```

Apply the function to the groups:

```
 grouped.apply(PChange)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It gives me a different way of thinking about manipulating these things. The index is treated as a string though, how would you attack that?

Comment: What I did was just add:
df['Date'] = [pd.to_datetime(x) for x in df.Date]

You think that's the best approach?